# Diameter protocol testing using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, diameter-protocol

Is there any opensource plugin available for diameter protocol testing using JMeter? 
I found "Computaris Top Testing Suite" which is based on JMeter and supports diameter protocol testing, but it is paid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing plugins, you could look into something like:

- [Java Diameter Library](http://i1.dk/JavaDiameter/)
- [jdiameter](https://code.google.com/p/jdiameter/)

You need to:

1. Download diameter client libraries
2. Put them into JMeter's /lib folder
3. Implement your test code via [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) (make sure that you use "groovy" as a language, see [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](http://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for explanation and instructions on installing groovy scripting engine support in Jmeter). You can check out [ExampleClient.java](https://code.google.com/p/jdiameter/source/browse/examples/guide1/src/main/java/org/example/client/ExampleClient.java) for reference.
4. Once it's ready and development is done you can run JSR223 Samplers as any other sampler types.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Seagull (http://gull.sourceforge.net/) to test diameter applications. Seagull is good in both testing and generating load for performance testing.

Also, a decent level of automation can be done using Seagull with Cucumber to automate the testing.